# Tweepy targeting a user for following

Tags: python, python-3.x, twitter, bots, tweepy

I find myself in need of a bot for following users on twitter.

When I say user I don't refer to a follower but to a random user that I will find with "Cursor". I'm trying to modify my twitter bot for liking on the timeline for a specific search into one that follows the users for that search. What I don't know how to implement is how do I exactly target a user from the timeline to "create_friendship()"? I'm not targeting a specific user so I don't want to have to specify the 'Id' or the "screen_name" etc.

Looking in Tweepy documentation I wasn't able to find a solution, maybe is under my nose but I'm a newbie and I could use some help.

This is the code for the twitter bot I use for liking tweets.

```py
import tweepy
import time

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler('','')

auth.set_access_token('','')

api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True, wait_on_rate_limit_notify=True)

search = "The searc"
nrTweets = 100


for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, search).items(nrTweets):
    try:
        print('User succesfully followed')
        tweet.favorite()  #in here i should be able to create a friendship as i like 
        time.sleep(60)
    except tweepy.TweepError as e:
        print(e.reason)
    except StopIteration:
        break
```

How can I turn this bot in one that follow people in the same fashion in which I like tweets? (for a search with a specific keyword)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I resolved if anyone cares.

```
# Write a function named collatz() that has one parameter named number. If
# number is even, then collatz() should print number // 2 and return this value.
# If number is odd, then collatz() should print and return 3 * number + 1

# Then write a program that lets the user type in an integer and that keeps
# calling collatz() on that number until the function returns the value 1.

# Add try and except statements to the previous project to detect whether the
# user types in a noninteger string. Normally, the int() function will raise a
# ValueError error if it is passed a noninteger string, as in int('puppy'). In the
# except clause, print a message to the user saying they must enter an integer.


try:
    number = int(input(("Enter an integer number ")))

    def collatz():

        global number

        if number % 2 == 0:
            print(int(number/2))
            number = (number/2)

        elif number % 2 == 1:
            print(int(3*number+1))
            number = (3*number+1)

        else:
            return

    while number != 1:
        collatz()

except:
    print("man, an integer number please! ")
```

Comment: I downvoted this answer because of the unneeded and gratuitous vulgarity of the UI.